# Interpolation during for each isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a weird error when I am running for each to go through the category. When I go and put the file name it works then but for some reason it isn't interpolating the title. This is the code for the html:

```
%h1 Catagories
- @catagories.each do |catagory|
  .col-md-6
    .catagory-lists
      %h2
        = catagory.title
      = image_tag('icons/#{catagory.title}.png', alt: '#{catagory.title}')
```

This is the output of this code:

```
<img alt="#{catagory.title}" src="/images/#{catagory.title}.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. It turns out that single quotation marks aren’t interpolated. So turning this:

```
= image_tag('icons/#{catagory.title}.png', alt: '#{catagory.title}')
```

into this:

```
= image_tag("icons/#{catagory.title}.png", alt: "#{catagory.title}")
```

fixes it